# Reuse UICollectionViewCell inside UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I already have an existing nib inheriting from `UITableViewCell` that I reuse in several `UITableView`s. If I create a `UICollectionView`, is there any way I can reuse that nib or do I need to recreate a new one inheriting from `UICollectionViewCell`?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the headers of UICollectionViewCell and UITableViewCell you'll see that they are not sub classes of a common base class.
Therefor you can't use TableCells instead of CollectionCells. You'll have to create a new CollectionCell.

Comment: It's amazing how hard it is to reuse any UI in iOS

Comment: Code example of how to reuse UI between collection/table cells?

Comment: No you can't do that :). I ment if you needed a code example of how collection views worked, nevermind my question. The only way would be to have a common UIView and add it to your Table or Collection cells, but you still need two different cells.

Comment: ya very unfortunate. I keep getting surprised by how hard it is to do UI for iOS. Be it either not able to easily reuse UI or having the UI so tightly bound together with constraints that it's impossible to make any modifications without breaking something. *sigh*